# Magnitude change to function resulting in different answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

A friend and I coded these two functions to answer a problem of how many coins you would need to give back for change if given the total value of the change. 
Quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies:

The magnitude of our change values are giving us different answers, however I was unsure how to explain this difference

```
def num_coins(cents):
    coins = [25, 10, 5, 1]
    count = 0
    for coin in coins:
        while cents >= coin:
            cents = cents - coin
            count += 1

    return count

#########

def coin_return(change):

    coin_options = [.25,.10,.05,.01]
    number_of_coins = 0

    for coin in coin_options:
        while change >= coin:
            number_of_coins += 1
            change = change - coin

    return number_of_coins

print(coin_return(.24))
print(num_coins(24))
```

The right output is six, two dimes and four pennies. The num_coins function returns this, however the coin_return function returns five. What's happening here? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Calculations done in floating point numbers cannot be tested for equality. When you expect `.01` the computer may have the value `.0099999`, for example.

Comment: Never use `float`s when needing an exact (to the last decimal) value. Due to their computer representation they will not be exact.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already pointed out in the comments, the issue is `float` approximation, as you can see from the code below:

```
def num_coins(cents, coins):
    count = 0
    for coin in coins:
        while cents >= coin:
            print(cents)
            cents = cents - coin
            count += 1
    return count
```

Used with `int` (exact):

```
print(num_coins(24, [25, 10, 5, 1]))
```

```
Cents: 24
Cents: 14
Cents: 4
Cents: 3
Cents: 2
Cents: 1
6
```

used with `float`:

```
print(num_coins(.24, [0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01]))
```

```
Cents: 0.24
Cents: 0.13999999999999999
Cents: 0.03999999999999998
Cents: 0.029999999999999978
Cents: 0.019999999999999976
5
```

---

you could work around this with the `round()` function, e.g.:

```
def num_coins(cents, coins, precision):
    count = 0
    for coin in coins:
        while round(cents, precision) >= round(coin, precision):
            cents = cents - coin
            count += 1
    return count


print(num_coins(.24, [0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01], 2))
# 6
print(num_coins(24, [25, 10, 5, 1], 0))
# 6
```

---

Another way would be to use [`math.isclose()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html):

```
import math


def num_coins(cents, coins):
    count = 0
    for coin in coins:
        while cents > coin or math.isclose(cents, coin):
            cents = cents - coin
            count += 1
    return count


print(num_coins(.24, [0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01]))
# 6
print(num_coins(24, [25, 10, 5, 1]))
# 6
```

---

Alternatively, you could stick to `int` or use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module from the standard library.